# Unable to Read Corrupted pdf using PyPDF2

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to merge 2 pdfs and write to one pdf using pypdf2.
Below is the code to read the file content

```
output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
for pdffile in self.files:
    input = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdffile, strict=False)
```

where self.files is file objects

I am getting below error when trying to read one particular pdf file
**TypeError: 'NumberObject' object has no attribute '**getitem**'**

When i ran ghostscript on the pdf file i found that the file is corrupted and the repaired one i am able to read without errors. I wanted to check if there is any way i can read the corrupted pdf file using pypdf2 only without errors?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't think anything could read a corrupted pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So in pypdf2 there is no option to correct the pdf before reading? I am able to open the pdf in adobe pdf reader

Answer (score 0):

You can fix broken PDF document with mutool from MuPDF:

```
mutool clean -d input.pdf output.pdf
```